# Passing a class as IntPtr

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using the Emgu CV when I come across this code:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("test.jpg");
Image<Bgr, byte> image2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("test2.jpg");
CvInvoke.cvSmooth(image, image2, SMOOTH_TYPE.CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5, 9, 9);
```

According to the definition of `cvSmooth()`, the first 2 parameters are `IntPtr`.

My question is that why is it valid to pass in a type of `Image<Bgr, byte>` into this?

Comment: Is `Image<Bgr, byte>` derived from [SafeHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain From what i can see, its base classes include  `IDisposable, ICloneable, IEquatable, IXmlSerializable, ISerializable`

Answer (score 0):

looks like `Image<TColor,TDepth>` has a `Ptr` property

[Ptr](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/da3313eb-329b-a859-cd1e-4d133f0b02d4.htm)

[Image](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/index.html)

I would change your code to read

```
Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>("test.jpg");
Image<Bgr, byte> image2 = new Image<Bgr, byte>("test2.jpg");
CvInvoke.cvSmooth(image.Ptr, image2.Ptr, SMOOTH_TYPE.CV_GAUSSIAN, 5, 5, 9, 9);
```

what version are you working with? I just went with the "Stable" version to find the docs

Comment: I am using version 2.4.10.1940.

Comment: Interesting. So does this mean that under C#, if i have a pointer attribute, the compiler will automatically include it inside? Meaning I can call `image` directly, instead of `image.Ptr`?

Comment: @JohnTan if the author of the code included an Explicit/Implicit conversion then the syntax will be a little neater. if you want to do it yourself this   [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889614/how-to-pin-a-pointer-to-managed-object-in-c)   should help get you started. unfortunataly you can't do Extension Methods for the Converters.